# How to find the difference in percentage

Tags: statistics, percentages

I am trying to solve a question, I predict one value as `1828.312` then I made changes in the data and predict the value second time which is `1843.198`. How I can calculate the change occur in percentage?

Comment: It's the $100$ times the difference, divided by the original value

Comment: So I only changed the value of `sodium` which was `440` in first dataset and result came as `1828.312` and then I changed sodium it into `44440` and result changed into `1843.198`. Should I do it like `1843.198 - 1828.312 = 14.886 `  and divided by original value? What is the original value here ?

Comment: The original value is $1828.312$, but if you want a percentage, you'll have to multiply by $100$.

Comment: (14.886 / 1828.312)*100 ? right ?

Comment: First, some calculus: `(44440-440) / 440 * 100 = 10000` And `(1843.198-1828.312) / 1828.312 * 100 = 0.81`. So, a change of $10000$% in the data produces a change of $0.81$% in the result.